# Finding the derivative of $\sin^n(x)\cos (nx)$

Tags: calculus

So I have to find the derivative of

$$\sin^{n}x\cos(nx)$$ if $n$ is a positive integer

I've simplified it down to

$$n(\cos (nx))(\cos (x))(\sin^{n-1}x) + (-n)(\sin(nx))(\sin^n(x))$$ 
using the product rule but according to my textbook I am supposed to get

$$n(\sin^{n-1}x)(\cos(n+1)x)$$

Could I have some help figuring out where I went wrong?

Thank you!

edit: Thank you very much to everyone who answered! Thank you also for the MathJax help.

Comment: $\cos((n+1)x) = \cos(nx)\cos(x)-\sin(nx)\sin(x)$.

Comment: sin^(n)x=sin^n (x) or sin(sin(....(sin(x)))))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you got is correct, but note that
$$n\sin^{n-1}x\cos x\cos(nx)-n\sin(nx)\sin^nx$$
$$=n\sin^{n-1}x(\color{red}{\cos x\cos(nx)-\sin x\sin(nx)})$$
$$=n\sin^{n-1}x\color{red}{\cos(n+1)x}$$

Comment: You beat me to it---this is a simple but effective use of color, too. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^n x\cos nx)$$
$$=-n\sin nx \cdot \sin^n x+\cos nx \cdot n\sin^{n-1} x \cdot\cos x$$
$$=n\sin ^{n-1} x(\cos nx \cdot\cos x - \sin nx \cdot \sin x)$$
$$=n\sin ^{n-1} x\cdot \cos(n+1)x$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, using chain rule as follows $$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^{n}(x)\cos(nx))$$ $$=\sin^{n}(x)\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(nx))+\cos(nx)\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^{n}(x))$$
$$=\sin^{n}(x)(-\sin (nx))\frac{d}{dx}(nx)+\cos(nx)(n\sin^{n-1}(x))\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(x))$$
$$=-\sin^{n}(x)\sin (nx)(n)+n\cos(nx)\sin^{n-1}(x)(\cos(x))$$
$$=n\sin^{n-1}(x)(-\sin(x)\sin (nx)+\cos(nx)(\cos(x)))$$
$$=n\sin^{n-1}(x)(\cos(nx)(\cos(x))-\sin(x)\sin (nx))$$
using $\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B=\cos(A+B)$, 
$$=n\sin^{n-1}(x)(\cos(nx+x))$$
$$=\color{red}{n\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(n+1)x}$$